# What happened to the AWS Billing Budget actions on Alert breach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-billing

I remember there was a time when we could set Actions to be triggered on alert breach in the AWS Billing Budgets. Couldn't find any documentation on this being dropped so though of asking if anyone else has noticed this ?

Guessing if that is thrown out we are left with setting up something triggered by an SNS topic for example. Would be interested to hear of your solutions of keeping a personal sandbox account automated to force a threshold instead of just alerting.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/budgets-controls.html

Comment: That's the one, thank you. Don't know what I was looking at (or not)